# Encountered TypeError: values is not iterable when trying to use search bar using react creatable select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a react application but encountered an error when I try to enter a value in a search bar using react creatable select, delete it using x button beside its value (not the x button on the far right), and then enter another value. How to prevent this error?

TypeError: values is not iterable
handleBlur [as onBlur]
setValues(removeDuplicates([...values, createOption(inputValue)], 'value'));

Thank you for your help.

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useState } from 'react';

const createOption = (label) => ({
  label,
  value: label,
});

const propTypes = {
  initialValues: PropTypes.array,
  onSearch: PropTypes.func,
  debug: PropTypes.bool
};

const removeDuplicates = (myArr, prop) => {
  return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
    return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
  });
}

export const useSearchBar = (props) => {
  PropTypes.checkPropTypes(propTypes, props, "property", "useSearchBar");

  let {
    initialValues = [],
    onSearch,
    loading
  } = props;

  // But use the users state if provided
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleBlur = (event) => {
    if(!inputValue || !inputValue.trim()) {
      return;
    }
    setValues(removeDuplicates([...values, createOption(inputValue)], 'value'));
    setInputValue('');
  };

  const handleValueChange = (val, actionMeta) => {
    setValues(val);
  };

  const handleInputValueChange = (inputValue) => {
    if(!inputValue) {
      return;
    }

    const re = /^[\d,\s]+$/;

    if (re.test(inputValue)) {
      setInputValue(inputValue.trim());
    }
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (!inputValue) return;
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'Enter':
      case 'Tab':
        setInputValue('');
        setValues(removeDuplicates([...values, createOption(inputValue)], 'value'));
        event.preventDefault();
        break;
      default:
    }
  };

  api.getSearchBarProps = userProps => ({
    ...props,
    components,
    value: values,
    onChange: handleValueChange,
    inputValue,
    onKeyDown: handleKeyDown,
    onInputChange: handleInputValueChange,
    onBlur: handleBlur,
    delimiter: ",",
    placeholder: "Search Transaction(s)...",
    loadingMessage: "Loading...",
    loading
  });

  return api;
}
```

Comment: does the `onChange` handler return a list or just a scalar value?

Comment: Hi codekaizer, it returns an object with {label: "11441764", value: "11441764"}